# how to set up default header in openAPI.json file to send the api_key as header in all the request

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

The famous https://petstore.swagger.io/ defines "api_key" in its "securitySchemas" . I followed the same and added "api_key" in my json file. All my restful web services requires this as a header parameter.

My assumption and also what I want it to define the header at one place in the openapi.json and all my webservices should get a request header when called from swagger.

The way it is defined in the petstore does no seems to work. I am setting the api_key . But it seems I have to explicitly define the header parameter in individually in each service definition.

[image]

Following is my openapi.json file

```
 {
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "connection": {
        "properties": {
          "connid": {
            "example": "LIMS1_107c5a8c1799d4cf8bb5ce295ab38954",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "type": "object",
        "$ref": "components/schemas/connection",
        "required": [
          "connid"
        ]
      }
    },
    "securitySchemes": {
      "api_key": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "api_key",
        "in": "header"
      }
    }
  },
  "externalDocs": {
    "description": "Find out more about Test API",
    "url": "http://www.Test.com/API"
  },
  "info": {
    "contact": {
      "email": "apiteam@Test.com"
    },
    "description": "Test LIMS RESTful and CRUD API",
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http://www.Test.com/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    },
    "termsOfService": "http://www.Test.com/terms/",
    "title": "Test LIMS API - OpenAPI 3.0.2",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "openapi": "3.0.2",
  "paths": {
    "/rest/authenticate": {
      "description": "authenticate and get a token",
      "summary": "authenticate and get a connection token",
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "connection"
        ],
        "operationId": "authenticate",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "description": "TEST datasource to connect to",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "username"
          },
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "description": "password of the user",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "password"
          },
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "description": "TEST datasource to connect to",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "datasource"
          },
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "description": "TEST Service to connect to",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "service"
          },
          {
            "required": false,
            "schema": {
              "description": "User role",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "role"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Connection",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/rest/close": {
      "description": "authenticate and get a token",
      "summary": "authenticate and get a connection token",
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "connection"
        ],
        "operationId": "close",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "description": "id of the connection to close",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "connectionid"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Connection",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/rest/function/ABS": {
      "description": "Answer the absolute value of the number\r\nx = ABS(number)",
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "REST API"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "in": "query",
            "name": "number"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Operation",
            "content": {
              "application/xml": {
                "schema": {
                  "format": "string",
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "x"
                }
              },
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "format": "string",
                  "type": "string",
                  "title": "x"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid funnction provided"
          },
          "405": {
            "description": "Validation Exception"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {"api_key" :  []}
  ],
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:8080/LIMS-REST/api/",
      "description": "description"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "connection",
      "description": "Connection management API ",
      "externalDocs": {
        "description": "Connection management API",
        "url": "http://www.Test.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "REST API",
      "description": "Test's non-crud APIs",
      "externalDocs": {
        "description": "Test's non-crud APIs",
        "url": "http://www.Test.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "objects",
      "description": "Test CRUD Operations on selected table",
      "externalDocs": {
        "description": "CRUD API Test LIMS. Can be done on selected tables",
        "url": "http://www.Test.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your JSON file. Did you also add the `security` key on the  global level or to operations? See https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/api-keys/

Comment: Thanks Helen, I have pasted my json file. I may be wrong. I added the global security header. But still not getting the auth-token header in the request

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution.

Please refer to https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json

We need to apply one of the the security defined in the 'securitySchemes' as defined in the 'components' object.

Security header can be applied globally by adding the security object as follows :

Refering to the petstore openapi.json, this is how you can apply the openapi.json globally.

```
"security": [
  {
    "api_key" :  []
  }
]
```